# Generalised Isospectrality of Graphs

Tags: rt.representation-theory, graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, isospectrality

**Q**: *Is there a graph matrix-representation (not necessarily an $n \times n$ matrix for an $n$-graph) such that isospectrality implies graph-isomorphism? For instance, would the simple distance-matrix do the job?*

**Background**: The 'can you hear the shape of a drum?' question can be answered of undirected graphs in the negative, but I do not know if the results are only for the adjacency and/or Laplacian matrix representations.

Comment: Note that existence of such matrix which is polynomially computable would imply polynomial GI test. Hence the matrix is probably large, or at least hard to compute.

Comment: Hi Mikhail - thanks for your comment. What is a 'GI test'?

Comment: Graph isomorphism test.

Comment: Ah, wonderful! That is a nice observation and it does not totally surprise me. For my part I'm initially banking on the distance matrix representation, which is obviously a higher complexity than adjacency and Laplacian. Do you know of any results on the complexity of computing distance matrices?

Comment: Distance matrix is easily computable in $O(|V||E|)$ time (could be faster for some graph classes). There are examples of non-isomorphic graphs with same distance matrices spectrum (for a lot of interesting examples and info see [here](http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/conferences/Belgrade2016Hansen.pdf)).

Comment: After some reflection, the answer seems to be a trivial 'yes'. We know there is an upper bound on computational complexity, say $f(n)$. If we imagine such an algorithm and each step in the process as a 'yes-no' type procedure, then we simply encode this in an $(f(n) \times f(n))$ diagonal matrix with binary entries on the diagonal. I'm finding it hard to think why this would fail but it should be easy to imagine fixing it.

Comment: If I understand the question well: because we can just take a diagonal matrix, this question boils down to, "Is it possible to write down an injective map from $n$-graphs to increasing sequences of length $m$?" One such construction might be to order the entries of the adjacency matrix to a sequence $a_i$ and then map it to the sequence $x_i = 3i + a_i$ of length $m=n^2$. Since $a_i\in \{0, 1, -1\}$, the sequence $x_i$ is increasing and from $x_i$ we can deduce both $i$ and $a_i$, hence we can recreate the adjacency matrix from $x_i$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a ridiculous solution using a $1 \times 1$ matrix! First, encode an $n \times n$ adjacency matrix $A$ by $a \lt 2^{\binom{n}2}$ where $a$ is the binary integer obtained by listing the above diagonal entries row by row. If you just want isospectrality to imply isomorphism then just encode it as $[a].$

Assuming that you want isospectrality *equivalent* to idomorphism, consider  all $n!$ adjacency matrices  getting an multi-set of $n!$ integers which we can give the natural order. Finally, encode the graph as the $1\times 1$ matrix $[2^{a_1+1}3^{a_2+1}\cdots]$ using the first $n!$ primes. The $+1$ is an inelegant way to avoid edge free graphs of various sizes being represented by $[1].$

This could be greatly enhanced, for example use instead the base $3$ integer with $n!-1$ $2$’s separating $a_12a_22a_32\cdots.$

‘Actually, one could just use the lexicographically least $n \times n$ adjacency matrix. This would have the vertices in decreasing order of degree. That alone is no help for regular graphs, but for others it might cut the number of cases.

Comment: I suppose this could even be encoded as a $1\times 1$ matrix whose entry is an element of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ by encoding the adjacency matrix as a binary decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Distance matrix is not going to help, as examples of non-isomorphic co-spectral strongly regular graphs would tell you.
The smallest examples like this exist on 16 vertices: [Shrikhande graph](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/Shrikhande.html).

In general, there seem to be logic-related obstacles for non-isomorphism certificates of this sort, related to 1st order logics with counting. This has started with the famous paper 
An Optimal Lower Bound on the Number of
Variables for Graph Identification by Cai, Furer and Immerman.